# C#: Integer value being returned as hexadecimal in VS 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, hex

I have a c# code snippets where i am creating a list of my custom class objects.When i am taking the count of that,its showing me a hexadecimal value in the quickwatch window.

[alt text http://img509.imageshack.us/img509/434/morrisissueinvs2008.jpg](http://img509.imageshack.us/img509/434/morrisissueinvs2008.jpg)

But if i type listItemCount.ToStrin(), i am getting the proper value as output (ie : 50061)

Any idea how to correct this ?

Comment: the value is 'shown' as hexadecimal .. not 'returned', the internal representation is the same (binary encoded)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right click the Watch Window and deselect the Hexadecimal Display of values.